# Loading rows into jsf datatable only on user request

Tags: jsf, datatable, sdo, ibm-jsf, hxdatatableex

Problem statement:

I have used `hx:dataTableEx` to display database table records.

I'm binding Service data object(relational record list) to `hx:dataTableEx`.

***Loading time is more due*** to number of records(fetch result gives more than 10000 records).

I have limited 50 rows per page and I used pagination(hx:pagerWeb) to view next set of records.

**How to make datatable loads only first 50 records which are to be displayed initially rest of the rows are to be fetched only on user clicking next button.**

Please help me to find the solution.

After trying the method suggested below, I have this problem.
[image: Page having datatable with initial setup]

When I click on commandlink with value 'A' datatable expands it's space on the screen(on page)but data is invisble. I don't know why datatable data is invisible.

Resulting screenshot:

[image: Empty expanded datatbale]

```
<h:dataTable  id="table" width="100%" value="#{myDataModelHandler.activeDataModel}"  binding="#{myHtmlDataTableHandler.htmlDataTable }" var="row" rendered=" #{myDataModelHandler.selectedLetter !=null }">
<hx:columnEx id="columnEx1">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText id="Column1Header" styleClass="outputText" value="Document Name">    </h:outputText>
    </f:facet>
    </hx:columnEx>
</h:dataTable>
```

I suspect that I have made error in binding the pagedlistdatamodel to the datatable component.

Please help me to troubleshoot this error.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to implement a data model for lazy loading.

Comment: Thank for your kind response. Please give a link to web page where sample data model designed with lazy loading, to get the logic.

Comment: http://dwuysan.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/using-jsf-2-2-features-to-develop-ajax-scrollable-lazy-loading-data-table/  + http://roneiv.wordpress.com/2008/01/02/lazy-loading-of-tables-in-jsf-working-with-large-amount-of-data/    Google is your best friend ! Try to be autodidact my friend!

Comment: @Sujan Sivagurunathan, Hi Sir, Please have a look on updated question. Thank you.